# Web component to redact sensitive data in PDF (or image)

Tags: .net, pdf, image-manipulation, pdf-manipulation

First use case - in our web application user scans or uploads (to server) pdf. Then we let him to black some sensitive data.

Right now I wrote some code that extract tiff from pdf and show it to user, who drow black rectangles in places he wants to black. Then he saves it back to server and I create new pdf from it, but I am not happy with how it works...

I am searching for a component (free of commercial) which do this for me (ideally without image extraction).

Best solution should:

1. **show** pdf/image in web application (could be IE only)
2. allow user to **modify** an image (in pdf) (adding black rectangles to the image)
3. allow user to **mark** some text in pdf and **change** any letter in marked text for one sign (rectangle, dot, etc.)
4. **save** pdf/image back to the server.

Information about components even with partial functionality would be appreciated.
Component may be IE only and both free and commercial.

Comment: The term for blacking out is redact.  Google "PDF redact" or "PDF redaction" and you will find info.  TIFF is more amenable to redaction.  There are no free PDF redaction tools that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft. Our [DotImage Document Imaging](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) product can do this (with the PDF Reader add-on).

I would suggest that the only way to do this correctly is to rasterize the page, and then save back a redacted image of the page to a PDF.  Anything else is very dangerous and could perhaps open up the recovery of the redacted text.

The one thing on your list it can't do is the character exchange with a symbol.  We could let you erase a character and draw something in its place (dealing with pixels in an image after rasterizing, not characters though)

Answer (score 1):

Qoppa has a Web PDF Markup component that can redact PDF documents. This is real redaction, where the content of the PDF document is permanently removed. Try it here: https://www.qoppa.com/pas/pdfmarkup/

Disclaimer: I work for Qoppa.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features). Please be aware that it is not a good aproach to just put black rectangles using PDF drawing instructions on top of your images if you want to remove this information in a secure way. This drawing instructions can be easily removed using the right tools.

Take a look on the post [Technical Note 11: Using the Amyuni PDF Creator libraries to redact a PDF document](http://www.amyuni.com/en/resources/technicalnotes/) for more details on this issue.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 0):

CIB doXiview can do removing content. You can do it for free also for uploaded pdf files online in their example Application.
https://doxiview.cib.de/showcase/index.html (Go to Redact).

But adding or editing text is not possible.